# Setting Environment Variable in Virtualenv Windows

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I am trying to set the environment variable in virtualenv. I have tried almost every approach from SO.In my settings.py i have declared `SECRET_KEY=os.environ['SECRET_KEY']` I have declared all my environment variable at the end of `venv\Scripts\activate` I tried `set,SET,setx,export` i also tried to put the environment variable in json but none of these are working. Whenever i try to run `python manage.py runserver` it is giving me  error
`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the SECRET_KEY environment variable`
I dont know what i am missing or what is going wrong?

Comment: I suppose you should be adding ENV variable values to system variables in computer settings.

Answer (score 0):

In venv\Scripts\activate.bat in last line add

```
set SECRET_KEY="XXXXXX"
```

and it will work